# Anypoint studio/Mule hangs during startup

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am new to Mule and Anypoint studio. I worked with Mule before. After a while I came back to work with it again. I upgrade to

`Anypoint Studio March 2015 Release
Version: 5.1.0
Build Id: 201503171252`

(sorry but I do not remember my old version and it over wrote by new version now)

After upgrading it hangs during start-up. It hangs during process of

[image]

My system :

```
Linux Mint 17 Qiana
Java -varsion : 
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I should add here when remove project from workspace, it does not hangs anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. By clearing cache for Mule/ Anypoint Studio it works.

```
./AnypointStudio /JAVA_HOME/bin/ -clean
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AnypointStudio /JAVA_HOME/bin/ -clean
```

Go to any AnypointStudio directory in command prompt and execute the above command. Make sure that `JAVA_HOME` variable is in the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

And you can increase `-XX:MaxPermSize` size in `<%installation_Direcotry%>/AnypointStudio.ini` 
place `-clean` attribute in `ini` file:

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-vmargs
-Xms584m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=784m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AnypointStudio/workspace
```