# How to install Mulesoft Anypoint studio on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Last time I worked with Anypoint Studio, my work laptop ran Windows 7. Now I'm using Ubuntu, with Win7 in a Virtualbox VM, and I'd love to install Anypoint Studio directly on Ubuntu rather than on the virtual Windows machine.

But I have a hard enough time finding a working download for Windows (most of the links point to a page on Mulesoft's site that no longer exists), nevermind any mention of getting it to work on Linux. But I'm hopeful that it *is* possible (because questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638952/anypoint-studio-mule-hangs-during-startup) indicate that users *are* using it this way). (To be explicit, this is not meant to be derogatory, sometimes I'm just not good with words.)

So:

- Is it possible to run Anypoint Studio in Linux (Ubuntu)?
- If yes, can you direct me to a download source and an installation guide?

(In case it matters, my exact OS version is Ubuntu MATE 15.10.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the newest (Beta) in http://blogs.mulesoft.com/biz/mule/new-mule-3-8-studio-6-0-beta-releases/

You can download the latest stable version in http://mule-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/5.4.0-NOV30/AnypointStudio-for-linux-64bit-5.4.0-201511302043.tar.gz

To get this link you have to register in https://developer.mulesoft.com/, inside Anypoint platform -> Design & build APIs -> Build APIs -> Download Studio

Comment: beta is still under test, not a stable release

Comment: That's a deep link. It works and I'll try installing it. Now that you mention it, I think I did register long ago; I'll look into reviving that profile.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous responses, **official** download links for **latest Anypoint Studio** can be found here:

- Linux: https://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/studio-linux
- Mac: https://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/studio-mac
- Windows: https://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/studio-windows